# the image url is not passing as a parameter in axios to api

Tags: vue.js, url, axios

this is the code that accept the image and convert to url

```
let images = ref([]);

    const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
      const files = event.target.files;

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        console.log(file.name);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => {
          images.value.push(reader.result);

        };
      }

      uploadImage(images.value);
    };
```

and this is the function that pass the url as a parameter in axios.

```
const uploadImage = (payload) => {
  console.log(payload);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // const formData = new FormData();
    // formData.append('image', payload);
    api.post('image-upload.php',{ image: payload})
      .then(response => resolve(response.data))
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });
};
```

the console payload has the url his it is:

```
Proxy(Array) {}
[[Handler]]
: 
Object
[[Target]]
: 
Array(1)
0
: 
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4YYZRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAA
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]
: 
false
```

but when it reach to backend
the paload and response is empty
this is the `payload in network`

```
  {image: []}
    image
    : 

[]
```

this is the `response` in the network

```
 array(1) {
      ["image"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
```

what could be the problem here. please help guys

Comment: Have you tried specifying sending it has a multipart/form-data in axios ?

Comment: no bro how can i do that.

Comment: You don't use promises with FileReader, while you should

Comment: i can't understand bro should i use promise with file reader or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer it seems strange but it works:

instead of this

```
   const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
      const files = event.target.files;

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        console.log(file.name);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => {
          images.value.push(reader.result);

        };
      }

      uploadImage(images.value);
    };
```

i move the function inside the reader.onload

```
const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
          const files = event.target.files;
    
          for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            const file = files[i];
            console.log(file.name);
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => {
              images.value.push(reader.result);
      uploadImage(images.value);
            };
          }
    
        
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set headers to multipart/form-data

```
api.post('image-upload.php',
        { image: payload },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        )
      .then(response => resolve(response.data))
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });
```

Also you can try to send the image as a blob.